# How to Deserialize the json object in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, json-deserialization

I want to bind json obect to my properties When I deserialize the json object and bind into the properties ,properties shows null values,please some one help me to resolve this.

this is my code

```
string s = "{\"response\":{\"status\":\"fail\",\"content\":{\"user_id\":\"56\",\"first\":\"kiran\",\"last\":\"kumar\",\"username\":\"kirankumar\"},\"msg\":\"shggh\"}}";

var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(s);

response myDeserializedObj = (response)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObj.ToString(), typeof(response));
```

this is properties

```
public class response
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public content content { get; set; }
}

public class content
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string username { set; get; }
}
```

Thanks,
karthik

Answer (score 1):

I copied you code and tested it in my machine and I could solve your problem
here is the solution

add the following class

```
public class ResponseWrapper
{
    public response response { get; set; }
}
```

replace your code with the following

```
string s = "{\"response\":{\"status\":\"fail\",\"content\":{\"user_id\":\"56\",\"first\":\"kiran\",\"last\":\"kumar\",\"username\":\"kirankumar\"},\"msg\":\"shggh\"}}";

response my = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseWrapper>(s).response;
```

I am sure this will work.

**UPDATE**

Another solution (Which is tested also) and **better** than the first one 
because it is more clean, and in this way you have not to create new wrapper class.

the solution is replace your string with the following string.

and all of your previous code will stay the same
here is the correct JSON string

```
string s = "{\"status\":\"fail\",\"content\":{\"user_id\":\"56\",\"first\":\"kiran\",\"last\":\"kumar\",\"username\":\"kirankumar\"},\"msg\":\"shggh\"}";
```

**UPDATE 2**

in the comments below of this answer you asked a completely a new question. 
here is your new question (I copied this from your comments)

```
public class responseWraper
{
    public response response { get; set; }
}

public class response
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public content content { get; set; }
}

public class content
{
    public Employees Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employees
{
    public string Employee_id { get; set; }
    public string Employee_name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how you are trying to deserialize this (also this copied from your comments)

```
string s = "{\"response\":{\"status\":\"success\",\"content\":{\"Employees\":[{\"Employee_i‌​d\":\"1\",\"Employee_name\":\"Sravan\",\"status\":\"1\"},}]}}}"; 
response my = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<responseWraper>(s).response;
```

**ANSWER**
your code has two problem

the first is you are using the `Employees` as array in the JSON string, but the type of the `Employees` property is not an array

the second problem that the JSON string itself is not valid. it has an errors
there is 4 `{` character but you have 5 `}` character inside it.

so you have to fix those two problem as the following

```
public class content
{
    public List<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

and the string is

```
 string s = "{\"response\":{\"status\":\"success\",\"content\":{\"Employees\":[{\"Employee_id\":\"1\",\"Employee_name\":\"Sravan\",\"status\":\"1\"},]}}}";
```

[image]

and if you have any other question , I will be happy to help you :)

Comment: I hope that you used the second solution instead of the first one, it is really more clean, and we can consider it more correct. And if this answer really solve your problem, you can mark it as acceptable answer this will help the other people who had a similar problem. glad that this worked for you :)

Comment: Ok Hakam, same as well  i tried for another string but i am getting error why can you tell me

Comment: Ok Hakam, same as well  I tried for another string but I am getting error.My I know , why I am getting error, I have follow your steps one by one ,this is my string.   string s = "{\"response\":{\"status\":\"success\",\"content\":{\"Employees\":[{\"Employee_id\":\"1\",\"Employee_name\":\"Sravan\",\"status\":\"1\"},}]}}}";
response my = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<responseWraper>(s).response;

Comment: and this is my properties 
public class responseWraper 
{
public response response { get; set; } 
}
public class response 
{
public string status { get; set; } 
public content content { get; set; } 
} 
public class content 
{
public Employees Employees { get; set; }
}
public class Employees 
{ 
public string Employee_id { get; set; }
public string Employee_name { get; set; } 
public string status { get; set;}
}

Comment: @kathik I updated my answer according to your comments. Please review the new updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try your JSON with http://json2csharp.com/.
Your current code would deserialize the following JSON:

```
{  
   "status":"fail",
   "content":{  
      "user_id":"56",
      "first":"kiran",
      "last":"kumar",
      "username":"kirankumar"
   },
   "msg":"shggh"
}
```

You are missing a root class with a single Property "response" with the type "Response"